# MySQL like exclude

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I have records like this:

> 1. WW.FK
> 2. WW.ZG., WW.FK.
> 3. WW.ZS., WW.ZG., WW.FK.
> 4. WW.ZS.

I want exclude this records that contains only "FK" and retrieve those that contains other than "Sk" but they can contain "SK"

If i use query

```
NOT LIKE '%WW.FK.%'
```

i get only

> 4. WW.ZS.

AND i use query

```
t LIKE '%WW.__.%' AND t not like '%WW.FK.%'
```

i will exclude all records that contains FK.

Records i want to get :

> 2. WW.ZG., WW.FK.
> 3. WW.ZS., WW.ZG., WW.FK.
> 4. WW.ZS.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to stop storing lists of things in strings.  This column contains a list of codes of some sort.  It should be stored in a junction table with one column for the original entity and another for each code.  Lists should (generally) be stored as rows in a table rather than as delimited strings.  Then you could rather easily express your query.

If you are stuck with this data structure, then perhaps regular expressions can help.  Something like this:

```
where not col rlike '^([^,]*[.]FK(, )+)+.$'
```

However, trying to figure out the right regular expression for each type of condition you might want is really just wasted work, because the right data structure makes this much easier.

Comment: i know i have bad structure, but i want get data somehow for now.
i want only records that contains '%WW.__.%'

Answer (score 0):

You can try using sub-query like.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `table_name` 
WHERE t NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
   t 
  FROM
    `table_name` 
  WHERE t LIKE '%WW.FK%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he just need parentheses.

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE (t LIKE '%WW.__.%') AND (t NOT LIKE '%WW.FK.%')
```

Worked when I was working a similar issue.

Comment: As to the earlier post regarding data structure, in my case this was a "one off" query. I needed to find orders for a software product with five old versions and exclude products that were just a related sticker. (LIKE "product%") AND (NOT LIKE "%sticker%").

Answer (score -1):

I think you should remove the percent sign :

```
`dual` NOT LIKE 'WW.FK'
```

Comment: This is wrong. He needs the percent signs, because he is checking on a substring.

Comment: But if the record he wants to remove is known exactly, and is equals to 'WW.FK', then a simple NOT LIKE 'WW.FK' works. Have I misunderstood something ?